# JavaScript unit testing best practices

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

This may be a broad and controversial question... but here we go.

I have never done unit testing in JavaScript before and I'd like to know what the best practice is with regards to its deployment.

Unit testing itself is quite straightforward (it's simple to create my own unit test or use existing frameworks such as QUnit).

My question is around deployment best practice; should unit test code be deployed into production?

For example: I have an object 'person' with the function 'getname()'; then I have the corresponding unit test for this to assert that the name is what I expect.

Quite simple, right?... but I have never seen an example of a JavaScript unit test "in the wild". So when people deploy their work into productions environments:

- Are they stripping the unit tests to save on bandwidth?
- Is there a particular way to handle unit test so that they don’t go into production?
- Is there a tool available that will enable me to unit test locally, but strip it for production?

I've never unit tested JavaScript before, so I'm not sure I'm asking the right question.

Comment: dont test getters and setters...

Comment: good point. getters/setter are too granular. i was only using it as an example. supposing it was a much more complicated function that got data through 3rd-party api's, once i write the corresponding unit test, should that be simply deployed into production "as is"?

Comment: _This may be a broad_, Indeed. Strategies vary by framework/available tooling. Are you talking about  a node.js project, something client side like Angular, Ember or some JavaScript that gets served from by your ASP page, etc.. you might want to be a bit more specific so we can get an idea what to focus on.

Comment: both actually. its a full javascript stack. i am not struggling with creating the tests. im particularly interested in deploying it into production. ive never seen it before on the internet (but i dont check every site i go to either) . is this because JS developers dont unit test (brief google search suggests a lot dont) or is there a procedure in-between development and deployment i am unaware of?

Comment: In general some tooling is used to minify/compress the source js files into a single file. (you can slightly compare it with compiling C/java sources). The tests files are usually excluded from this compression. @pablochan touches such build tools in his answer,

Comment: @X0r0n did you find the answer to your questions? this will help stackoverflow find the answers to their problems faster. if none of the responses are suitable answers, please update your question to elaborate on your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should unit test code be deployed into production?

No.

> Are they stripping unit test to save on bandwidth?

Yes. There's also no benefit of deploying tests to production.

> Is there a particular way to handle the unit tests so that they don’t go into production?

Write them in separate files. Don't deploy those files. A clear naming convention helps, e.g. all test files end in `.spec.js`.

> Is there a tool available that will enable me to unit test locally, but strip it for production?

Yes. You can use [Grunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunt_(software)), [Gulp.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulp.js), [Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), etc. to skip test files when preparing a distribution package.

Answer (score 0):

You would *never* have unit tests near production. Units of code should not be environment dependent.

If a unit of code works one way in a local development environment, it should work the same way in a test or production environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Tests should always be run locally prior to production deployment.**

**Test code should not be run during a production deploy** - instead, it should be used to pass builds in test deployment environments like [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (CI) or [QA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance) (have a look at [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) for continuous integration servers, and [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/jenkins.html) for running tests, perfect for these scenarios). Having a separate QA environment will allow you to privately mirror production and check for bugs encountered post release.

This is obvious, but tests should also be run locally.

Use a continuous integration server to manage your deployments. Common practice is to fail the build if a test failure is encountered, indicating the application is not ready for production release.

You should then take the tagged application (assuming you are using Git tags for versioning your snapshots) matching your CI or QA environment (assuming all tests pass), and use that as a metric for signing off on your production application, indicating it is ready for production release and deployment.

**You should not be running tests during production deploys**, rather running them in environments preceding production.

*This of course is an over simplification and your situation may vary depending on your applications needs.*